# What are the advantages of warrants over options?

Tags: options, online-trading, warrants

Is there any advantages of trading warrants over options?

Comment: smaller minimum trade and lower standardization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Warrants are essentially long term options. There are several differences:

- The company issues warrants and keeps the capital raised from them.  If exercised (call warrants), the company issues new shares.
- Options are based on 100 shares. They trade on option exchanges and the money is between two traders.  You can buy as few as one warrant.
- Options tend to be more liquid, particularly those of nearer term expiration.
- Option contracts are standardized.  Warrants are not.
- Exercised warrants lead to dilution.  Options do not.